# How do I prevent the page from scrolling when the usestate changes in react hook?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
    const [posttotal, settotal] = React.useState(0);

> here is changing useState value. and page scrolling to top.

   function changeVerdigiHizmetler(slct,fiyat){

        if (slct==true) {
            settotal(posttotal+Number(fiyat))

        } else {
            settotal(posttotal-Number(fiyat))
        }

    }
   
   
    function changeVerdigiHizmetler_EkHizmetler(event,adi,slct,fiyat){

        changeVerdigiHizmetler(slct,fiyat)
 

    }
```

**When I go to the onclick event, I get the price total and print it on the screen with posttotal.
There is no problem in operation.

But the page scrolls up because the useState has changed. I want to avoid this as it is annoying.

How can I prevent the page from scrolling?**

Comment: This issue will be helpful for you : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469629/stop-scroll-bar-from-moving-to-top-when-rerendering-reactjs

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. The same problem persists when I completely remove the component.